# Android Okhttp do not show/load cached response

Tags: android, okhttp, offline-caching

Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211333/correct-way-of-setting-up-cache-for-okhttp-in-android)

I'm trying to set up the cache for OkHttp3. I am working on a mapping application where request are sending continuously to fetch map tiles/data. I have setup cache as follow:

```
try {
            if (mContext.getExternalCacheDir() != null) {
                String mapsCacheDirectoryPath = getMapsCacheDirectoryPath(mContext);
                File httpCache = new File(mapsCacheDirectoryPath + "/tile_cache");
                Cache okTileCache = new Cache(httpCache, 100 * 1024 * 1024);
                okClient.setCache(okTileCache);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And i am also using Interceptor to add Cache-Control header as:

```
okClient.interceptors().add(
            new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                    String cacheHeaderValue = isInternetConnectionAvailable(context, false)
                            ? "public, max-age=2419200"
                            : "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=2419200";
                    Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder().build();
                    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                    return response.newBuilder()
                            .removeHeader("Pragma")
                            .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                            .header("Cache-Control", cacheHeaderValue)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        );


        okClient.networkInterceptors().add(
                new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                        String cacheHeaderValue = isInternetConnectionAvailable(context, false)
                                ? "public, max-age=2419200"
                                : "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=2419200";
                        Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder().build();
                        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                        return response.newBuilder()
                                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                                .header("Cache-Control", cacheHeaderValue)
                                .build();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Now when i run app with Wifi enabled. It starts caching data in specified storage location. But When i turn off wifi and restart app it do not load/show data from cache. When request is sent i onFailure gets called with error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.290.75:8787

It is suggested that i should close response body to make it work so i have added response.body().close() but still got the same error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: hi，I got same error,what's the problem with you?